# Access IIS on Windows server 2012 through wireless directly without router

Tags: windows, iis, networking, webserver, dhcp

Just bought a new server and installed windows server 2012 on it. The server has a wireless device.

I am planning to deploy a web application in that server and wanting all user to connect to this server through wireless directly to that server(not using any router/switches). So basically, the windows server 2012 have DHCP installed to assign IP address to any user that connect to that server wirelessly; and user able to navigate to the website deployed in the IIS.

How do I configure the windows server 2012 to offer this feature? 
The end result would be:
-> User can see the WIFI name that is broadcast-ed by the windows server 
-> Then user connect to it with some security protection(Ex: WEP) 
-> Then user open his browser and navigate to the web application by typing the local IP address.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: This type of configuration is well outside industry best-practice for security, performance, and usability.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The purpose of the server device is to provide a portable solution for web based training on board ships or remote facilities. The pads connecting need only get web traffic from teh servers IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Routers/firewalls have all the same functionality - wireless and built-in DHCP server with at least one **major** advantage - being designed and made exclusively for the job. Giving direct **AND** wireless access to **ANY** business resource is a **NO-NO**.
Web server ideally should be in DMZ of their own, separate subnet is a definite plus. And obviously **NOT** connecting directly to lots of clients on the same network - if you do what you are asking for, you automatically open **ALL** your computers on the whole network if any one is compromised - **NOT** a good idea.